# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ENTITY'

Tags: product-attribute

I'm doing a module with a new type of product using a helper/model for virtual product, and inserting a new attribute via SQL setup (in Module ...)

My <del>helper</del> model:

```
class ItepCompany_Incomm_Model_Product_Virtual
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Virtual
{
}
```

**My pro mysql-install-0.1.0.php code is:**

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(ItepCompany_Incomm_Model_Product_Virtual::ENTITY, 'terms_of_use', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'sort_order' => 4,
    'label'         => 'Terms of use',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => true,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Only when accessing the admin panel of the error:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ENTITY' ... \ sql \ add_product_attribute \ MySQL4-install-0.1.0.php on line 3

Did not generate anything in the log, which caused the problem?

Comment: ItepCompany_Incomm_Model_Product_Virtual::ENTITY this cause the problem have you defined the constant?

Comment: for example, the $this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY.... , takes the folder app/core/mage/catalog/model/product and creates in the every type of product, i need to create in my custom type of product.... the constant have definitions in model wich i was using, but this error is a problem

Answer (score 3):

```
ItepCompany_Incomm_Model_Product_Virtual::ENTITY
```

you are trying to get the constant that are not define in your class.

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY
```

in this class ENTITY constant in define

```
const ENTITY                 = 'catalog_product';
```

so solution is that use the default product ENTITY or define in your custom class.